# Does it take long time to turn AC unit around?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

I am wondering if it can take a full day of work to turn around AC unit like in this post .

[Must my new air conditioning unit be 3 feet from the wall (or positioned backward)?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/89506/must-my-new-air-conditioning-unit-be-3-feet-from-the-wall-or-positioned-backwar?noredirect=1#comment128227_89506)

Comment: Recently had a unit relocated 10' (to make space available for a different construction project), the steps required are basically what @Tester101 supplied in his answer.  The project required 6 hours of labor.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't do it yourself, but an HVAC technician likely could. Moving the unit likely requires:

1. Evacuating the refrigerant
2. Reconfigure (and potentially rerun) the line sets.
3. Reconfigure (and potentially rerun) electrical.
4. Physically moving the unit.
5. Charging the system back up with refrigerant.

You could probably do number 4, and maybe number 2 & 3 if you have plumbing and electrical skills. It's doubtful that you have the tools and training required to do numbers 1 and 5.

Also, see my [updated answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/89517/33) to that question, that explains why you might not want to rotate the unit.